# Get netfilter statistics on the command line

Tags: iptables, firewalld, netfilter, nftables

I am finally switching from the old iptables to the new netfilter (specifically using firewalld) to configure my computers and servers but so far I have failed to find any newer alternative to the good old `iptables -vnL` for quickly getting current statistics.

What's the appropriate command to use here instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print all netfilter rules to check current counter values

```
nft list ruleset
```

Edit:
Since firewalld probably does not add counters to nft rules, you will not get traffic statistics using firewalld with nftables.